# How add a button to buttonBar in WizardForm

Tags: c#, winforms, wizard

all, I'm creating a wizard base on WizardForm, but I can't add a new button after "Cancel";
do you known any way to do that?

Thanks
Dma

Comment: What is this WizardForm? Which UI framework are you using (WinForms, WPF, Silverlight, ASP.NET)?

Comment: @Joe, WinForms, Microsoft.WizardFramework.WizardForm; I'm developing a plug-in for VS2008; I use this class as wizard base class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use reflection in C# to get the _buttonBar and add the help button after "Cancel".